# Some topics have issues with their versions

Tags: bug, documentation, versions

Here are some examples:

## [image: sqlite: Python 2.xPython 3.x], [image: Python 2.x]

Note that none of these have versions selected if you edit.

---

Also, some topics have only one version selected:

## [image: Python 3.x3.5], [image: Python 3.x3.4]

There are more, so if you need links, I can post them.